# Python unittest assertraises error

Tags: python, exception, traceback, unit-testing

I had this weird trouble running my unittest in Python:
  I used assertRaises, and running the unittest raised the correct exception, but the test still failed.  Ok I cannot really explain it, please see the traceback for yourself:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/chianti/PycharmProjects/Programming_Project/Part1and4/Part1and4Test.py", line 32, in test_non_alpha_name
self.assertRaises(RestNameContainNonAlphaError, RestaurantName(self.non_alpha_name))
File "/Users/chianti/PycharmProjects/Programming_Project/Part1and4/InputCheck.py", line 29, in __init__
raise RestNameContainNonAlphaError('There are non alphabetic characters that I can not recognize!')
RestNameContainNonAlphaError: There are non alphabetic characters that I can not recognize!


Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/chianti/PycharmProjects/Programming_Project/Part1and4/Part1and4Test.py", line 24, in test_non_string_name
self.assertRaises(InputNotStringError, RestaurantName, self.non_string_name)
File "/Users/chianti/anaconda/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 473, in assertRaises
callableObj(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/chianti/PycharmProjects/Programming_Project/Part1and4/InputCheck.py", line 33, in __init__
raise InputNotStringError('Not String! The input is supposed to be a string type!')
InputNotStringError: Not String! The input is supposed to be a string type!
```

Why ?????????? Any ideas are appreciated !!! THANK YOU

---

Here is my unittest:

```
class RestaurantNameTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):

    self.non_string_name = 123
    self.valid_name = 'Italian rest '
    self.non_alpha_name = 'valid ** n'

def tearDown(self):

    self.non_string_name = None
    self.valid_name = None
    self.non_alpha_name = None

def test_non_string_name(self):

    with self.assertRaises(InputNotStringError):
        RestaurantName(self.non_string_name)

def test_valid_name(self):

    self.assertEqual(RestaurantName(self.valid_name).__str__(), 'Italian rest')

def test_non_alpha_name(self):

    self.assertRaises(RestNameContainNonAlphaError, RestaurantName(self.non_alpha_name))
```

If you need to see the definition of RestaurantName, here it is:

```
class RestaurantName():

def __init__(self, input_contents):

    self.name = input_contents

    if IsValidString(self.name):

        self.no_space_name = self.name.replace(' ', '')

        if str.isalpha(self.no_space_name):
            pass
        else:
            raise RestNameContainNonAlphaError('There are non alphabetic characters that I can not recognize!')

    else:

        raise InputNotStringError('Not String! The input is supposed to be a string type!')

def __repr__(self):

    return 'RestaurantName(%s)' % self.name.strip()  

def __str__(self):

    return self.name.strip()
```

Thanks again

Comment: Please show us the function `test_non_alpha_name` in `Part1and4Test.py`.

Comment: I am so sorry. I apologize for my mistake in my first version of problem description. I have updated my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback doesn't match your description of the problem (nor your code FWIW). The error you get is in `test_non_alpha_name()` which you didn't post but from your error message looks like:

```
self.assertRaises(
    RestNameContainNonAlphaError, 
    RestaurantName(self.non_alpha_name)
    )
```

This is not the correct way to use `assertRaises()`. You must pass `ExpectedExceptionClass, callable, *args, **kw` to `assertRaises`, and `args` and `kw` will be passed to your callable. IOW you want:

```
self.assertRaises(
    RestNameContainNonAlphaError, 
    RestaurantName, 
    self.non_alpha_name
    )
```

The reason is simple: the way you currently call it, the exception is triggered *before* the call to `assertRaises`.

As a side note:

- your tearDown method is useless
- there's already a builtin exception for wrong types, it's named `TypeError`
- there's also a builtin exception for wrong values which is named `ValueError`

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I apologize for my mistake in my first version of problem description. Your explanation is perfect! Now I know better about assertRaises, and better, I learned TypeError and ValueError.

Comment: I am sorry, I tried TypeError and ValueError, they worked fine in my unittest. But when I used `self.assertRaises(
    RestNameContainNonAlphaError, 
    RestaurantName, 
    self.non_alpha_name
    )` I still got the same error. Does it have something to do with my definition of RestaurantName?? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Chianti5: if you raise a ValueError in your code under test and expect a RestNameContainNonAlphaError in your test code then the test will very obviously fail. I mentionned these exceptions because they already exist, are standard, and are approriate for you use case but you can reinvent the wheel if you prefer ;)